# GitLab stop pipeline when condition does not match

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I stop a pipeline based on a condition in my first job?

I have a package which had no versioning changes and in this case all subsequent jobs should not run.

```yaml
build:version:
  image: node:16.13.0
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - npm install @semantic-release/{commit-analyzer,release-notes-generator,changelog,gitlab,git} @google/semantic-release-replace-plugin
  script:
    - npx semantic-release --dry-run --no-ci
    - export BUILD_VERSION=$(npx semantic-release --dry-run | grep 'The next release version is' | sed -E 's/.* ([[:digit:].]+)$/\1/')
    - if [ -z "$BUILD_VERSION" ]; then echo "There was no version change!"; else echo "Next version is $BUILD_VERSION"; fi
```

If `$BUILD_VERSION` is empty here, I want the pipeline to stop. How can I achieve that?

I haven't found anything about this in the GitLab docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the job exit with a non-zero exit code.

GitLab's default behavior is to stop the pipeline and not run subsequent stages when a job fails. So, you can use a job to stop the subsequent pipeline stages simply by exiting with a non-zero exit code.

One possible trick you can use is to place this job in the special `.pre` stage. This stage always runs first, no matter what. This way, you can assure that this job you use runs before all other stages. If this job fails, no jobs from all other stages will run (assuming they do not declare `needs:[]`).

```yaml
check_variables:
  stage: .pre
  script: |
    # evaluate some logic
    if [[ -z "$BUILD_VERSION" ]]; then
        echo "You must set the build version"
        exit 1  # fail the job
    else # otherwise, let the job succeed
        echo "all good"
    fi
```